# C++ :: Как записать текст в файл с переносом строк?

Tags: c++

Текст пишется в файл, но без переносов - слитно.
Текст такого вида (строка) "xxxxxxxxxxxxx\r\nyyyyyyyyyyyyy\r\nzzzzzzzzzzzzz".
Как реализовать запись в файл текста с переносом строк, вот так:
xxxxxxxxxxxxx
yyyyyyyyyyyyy
zzzzzzzzzzzzz

```
.
.
.
///////////////////////////////////////

// initiation string
GetString getstring_note;
const String_t info_txt[] = { getstring_note.GetInfo(1) }; // получаем строку с текстом
const String_t file_name = getstring_note.GetNames(0); // получаем имя файла

///////////////////////////////////////

bool Note::DropNote(const WString_t&& drop_path) noexcept
{
    .
    .
    .
      DWORD written = 0;
      for (auto inf : info_txt)
      {
        WriteFile(file, inf.c_str(), inf.size(), &written, 0); // пишем текст в файл
      }
      CloseHandle(file);
      return true;
    .
    .
    .
}
.
.
.
```

Comment: Vladimir Банально, Карл).. ничего поумней не придумал)? Ес-тес-твен-но пробовал))

Comment: файл то писался с переносами, просто видимо файл открываете в бинарном режиме (то есть пишется побайтово). И в этом случае при записи `\n` именно один байт и будет записан. А блокнот (которым скорее всего Вы и проверяете свой результат) не умеет показывать такой перевод строк. То есть, это не код пишет файл без переносов, это средство просмотра скорее всего не умеет их отображать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Видно коронавирус действует на умы).. что ж, отвечу сам на свой же вопрос:

```
///////////////////////////////////////

// initiation string
GetString getstring_note;

// replace character
String_t format_txt(String_t&& txt)
{
  std::size_t pos = 0;
  while ((pos = txt.find('|', pos)) != std::string::npos)
  {
    txt.replace(pos, 1, "\x0D\x0A");
    pos++;
  }

  return txt;
}

// we get formatted text
String_t txt_format = format_txt(getstring_note.GetInfo(1));
const String_t info_txt[] = { txt_format };

///////////////////////////////////////
```

Comment: а почему поиск символа '|' ?

Comment: а почему бы нет) у меня это общий разделитель в тексте формы